# Snake Yaml: How to load yaml file resolving property placeholders

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, snakeyaml

We have a spring boot application with configuration being driven from `application.yml` file. In this configuration file we use the feature of defining a property by referring to another property inside the same `application.yml` file:

```
my-games-app:
  base-property: foo
  games:
    - game-one:
        game-name: ${my-games-app.base-property}one
        game-location: ${my-games-app.base-property}/one
    - game-two:
        game-name: ${my-games-app.base-property}two
        game-location: ${my-games-app.base-property}/two
```

And we have a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean loading `games` configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-games-app.games")
public class GamesConfig {
    private Map<String, Game> games;
    ...
}
```

Useless to say the above is just an example, in reality it is a very complex setup with `GamesConfig` bean being used as a constructor argument for many other beans inside our application:

```
@Component
public class GamesRunner {
    private final GamesConfig gamesConfig;
    ...
}
```

Everything works as expected. The problem we have is related to testing the beans where `GamesConfig` is injected; in the above example `GamesRunner`. At the moment we use `@SpringBootTest` to get hold of the beans we want to test. This again, works OK but the main inconvenient is that the whole application needs to be started in order to access the `GamesConfig` bean. This means setting up a lot of infrastructure such as a Database a JMS message broker and a Kafka broker. This takes time and makes our CI builds longer to run which started to become a bit of an inconvenient. Because the beans we want to test don't need any other setup than having the `GamesConfig` constructor argument provided we would prefer to have unit tests in place rather than integration tests as they are much faster to run.

In other words, we want to be able to recreate `GamesConfig` by hand by parsing our `application.yml` with a test helper method. To do this we use [snakeyaml](https://github.com/snakeyaml) library:

```
public final class TestHelper {
    public static GamesConfig getGamesConfig() {
        var yaml = new Yaml();
        var applicationYaml = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(readResourceAsString("application.yml");
        return createGamesConfig(applicationYaml.get("games");
   }
   
   private static GamesConfig createGamesConfig(Object config) {
      // The config Object passed here is a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`
      // as defeined in our `games` entry in our `application.yml`.
      // The issue is that game name and game locations are loaded exactly like 
      // configured without property place holders being resolved
     return gamesConfig;
   }
}
```

We resolved the issue by manually parsing the property placeholders and looking up their values in the `application.yml` file. Even if our own property placeholder implementation is quite generic, my feeling is that this extra work is not needed as it should be a basic expectation the library would have some specific set up to do this out of the box. Being very new to snakeyaml I hope someone else hit the same problem and knows how to do it.

We use snakeyaml because it just happened to be in the class path as a transitive dependency, we are open to any suggestions that would achieve the same thing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, from what I understand, is that you want to annotate your test with `@SpringBootTest` but not load any beans except `GamesConfig`?.

Comment: Not really as this will still take much longer to execute comparing to a unit test because spring boot will still have to do their initialisation stuff. What we want instead, is to build that config ourselves by loading yaml file in a map and then resolve `my-games-app.games`. The issue is that snakeyaml resolves the `game-one.game-name` as `${my-games-app.base-property}one` rather than resolving the placeholder and resolve to `fooone`. Snakeyaml seems to be a pretty good library and my question was about can snakeyaml (or other library) be configured in such a way to resolve the placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, SnakeYAML only supports [substitution of environment variables](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Variable%20substitution), which is why what you want is not possible as far as I know. What you can do instead, of course, is simply use Spring's classes without setting up a full `ApplicationContext`.

For example, assuming your game config from above, you could use:

```java
final var loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
final var sources = loader.load(
        "games-config.yml",
        new ClassPathResource("games-config.yml")
);
final var mutablePropertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
sources.forEach(mutablePropertySources::addFirst);

final var resolver = new PropertySourcesPropertyResolver(mutablePropertySources);
resolver.setIgnoreUnresolvableNestedPlaceholders(true);

System.out.println(resolver.getProperty("my-games-app.games[0].game-one.game-name"));
System.out.println(resolver.getProperty("my-games-app.games[0].game-one.game-location"));
System.out.println(resolver.getProperty("my-games-app.games[1].game-two.game-name"));
System.out.println(resolver.getProperty("my-games-app.games[1].game-two.game-location"));
```

which outputs:

```
fooone
foo/one
footwo
foo/two
```

If you are actually interested in how Spring does it, a good starting point is the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e565d2cabb01539933195b0d1bc3b55992fb9c84/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java) of the [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) class.

Comment: I would have expected either `my-games-app.games[0].game-name` or `my-games-app.game-one.game-name` but not both. Accept it as a valid answer because gives us a way of resolving placeholders without us having to implement resolving logic plus having the advantage of running exactly what a `@SpringBootTest` would most likely do. Good suggestion.

Comment: @Julian Well, `games` is a _list of maps_ with only one key (`game-one/two`) _of maps_ with two keys (`game-name/location`), so from that perspective it makes sense, in my opinion. You could also represent it either as a list of maps (for which you would have to remove `game-one/two`) or, maybe even better, don't use a list and just represent it as a map of maps. Whether that's possible/sensible depends of on your requirements of course.